# find and delete next array inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$items= [{"link": "1ndexample","mime_type": "image"},{"link": "2ndexample","mime_type": "vide"},{"link": "3ndexample","mime_type": "image"},{"link": "4ndexample","mime_type": "image"}]
```

I want find items with video mime_type, then remove the next items.
For example in the above code, return :

```
[{"link": "1ndexample","mime_type": "image"},{"link": "2ndexample","mime_type": "vide"},{"link": "4ndexample","mime_type": "image"}]
```

How can I do it?
I wrote this code:

```
foreach($items as $item){
    if($item['mime_type'] == 'video'){
        unset (next($items));
    }
}
```

But it returns :

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in
> (unset (next($items));)

Comment: What's your expected output? next() moves the internal pointer to the next element and returns nothing and unset() can't unset nothing.

Comment: So how can I unset next array in foreach?

Comment: What's the expected output? Also, it should be `video` instead of `vide` in your JSON example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier to access and delete the item in a `for` loop:

```
<?php
$items = json_decode('[{"link": "1ndexample","mime_type": "image"},{"link": "2ndexample","mime_type": "video"},{"link": "3ndexample","mime_type": "image"},{"link": "4ndexample","mime_type": "image"}]');

for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
    if ($items[$i-1]->mime_type === 'video') {
        unset($items[$i]);
    }
}

var_dump($items);
```

Comment: When deleting items in a for loop it is safer to do it backwards.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Good point, thank you. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me why it is safer to do it backwards ?

Comment: @Learner231 Because you wouldn't be able to read the already deleted (next) item. Example array `[0 => 'video', 1 => 'video', 2 => 'image']`... First iteration of the loop checks that item indexed 0 is `video` and removes the item indexed 1. Second iteration wants to check the item indexed 1 but it's already deleted... When you're looping backwards, there's no risk of accessing already deleted items.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works if you use the key:

```
foreach($items as $key => $item){
    if($item['mime_type'] == 'video'){
        unset($items[$key+1]);
    }
}
```